# CSS How to put the headline infront of the border?

Tags: html, css

So I need this to happen in an article:

[image: Screenshot]

I already found a solution for this but I’d like one that does not abuse CSS.

The one I found was using a `<legend>` element. I’m looking for a solution that is completely standards compliant.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this website, this is not what should happen... :)

Comment: Just click on the text and you'll see the picture.

Comment: Maybe give the headline a negative margin values so it goes outside the box.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the current CSS & HTML you’re using?

Comment: @AhmedHammad I already did that but then it doesn't scale with the website. It loses its position when you zoom in or make the window smaller

Comment: @AhmedHammad is right, what doesn't scale show some code and the specific problem.

Comment: sorry for my bad preparation. As I said I'm new  to this.

Comment: @benvc I tried it with a negative margin but my teacher said thats not clean. and I dont want someone to code it for me. I just need a tipp or some explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative margins (and semantic html and relative units):

```css
article {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  border: .125em solid;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

article h1 {
  /* stretch to fit */
  display: table;
  /* set font size and line height */
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* set margins wrt line height */
  margin-top: -.75em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>AAAAAAAA</h1>
  <p>ASDF</p>
</article>

<article>
  <h1>AAAAAAAA</h1>
  <p>ASDF</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

```css
.div {
  border:2px solid #000;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.above_text {
  position:absolute;
  background:#fff;
  top:-10px;
  left:30px;
  z-index:3;
}

.inside_text {
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="above_text">AAAAA</div>
  <div class="inside_text">ASDF</div>
</div>
```